# When the keyboard appears, the Flutter widgets resize. How to prevent this?

Tags: keyboard, resize, widget, textfield, flutter

I have a Column of Expanded widgets like this:

```
 return new Container(
      child: new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: convertFrom,
          ),
          new Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: convertTo,
          ),
          new Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: description,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

It looks like this:

[image]

`convertFrom`, includes a TextField. When I tap on this text field, the Android keyboard appears on the screen. This changes the screen size, so the widgets resize like this:

[image]

Is there a way to have the keyboard "overlay" the screen so that my Column doesn't resize? If I don't use `Expanded` widgets and hardcode a height for each widget, the widgets don't resize, but I get the black-and-yellow striped error when the keyboard appears (because there isn't enough space). This also isn't flexible for all screen sizes.

I'm not sure if this is an Android-specific or Flutter-specific.

Comment: In your Scaffold body use a SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: [This example will help you - Flutter login page With Background Image](https://androidride.com/flutter-background-image/#bg_login_page)

Comment: For future readers : If possible then remove the scaffold it will solve the problem

Answer (score 650, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

`resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` is now *deprecated*.

The updated solution is to set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` property to `false`.

---

**Original Answer**

In your `Scaffold`, set `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` property to `false`.

Comment: Is there any way to produce a similar effect to `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`? If I add `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` to the scaffold it ends up covering the TextField.

Comment: I do not know about android, but it is generally a good practice to wrap your layout inside a ListView in this case

Comment: @KishanVyas same with me image is gone.

Comment: `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` is deprecated, use `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` [check this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56095293/5212904)

Comment: This does nothing of the sort suggested in the question.   All widgets underneath the keyboard still resize.

Comment: ```resizeToAvoidBottomPadding``` removes the default functionality to keep UI above the keyboard so  if you set it false then UI will be covered by the keyboard 

checkout solution here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62245570/9955978

Comment: it works when I adding "resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,"

Answer (score 128):

Most other answers suggest using `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding=false`. In my experience this allows the keyboard to cover up text fields if they are underneath where the keyboard would appear.

My current solution is to force my column to be the same height as the screen, then place it in a `SingleChildScrollView` so that Flutter automatically scrolls my screen up just enough when the keyboard is used.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        ),
        child: IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              // CONTENT HERE
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I use `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` so that the user cannot scroll around themselves.

Comment: I tried your way without `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` and all looks fine except for user can try to swipe up and down and they can see the overscroll glow. When I use the `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` it gives me the same behavior as `resizeToAvoidBottomInset`

Comment: Set the primary property to false.

Comment: but using `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` makes it so it doesn't get scrolled up with the keyboard too.

Comment: remove, NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() line of the SingleChildScrollView Widget, or replace ClampingScrollPhysics() to there. then it will scroll up with the keyboard.

Comment: I had the same behavior with or without the IntrinsicHeight Widget. The documentation says to avoid using it: "This class is relatively expensive. Avoid using it where possible."

Comment: SingleChildScrollView perfectly solved my problem that keyboard cover my TextField which lead to can not see what is inputing.

Answer (score 42):

Set [`resizeToAvoidBottomInset`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomInset.html) to `false` instead of [`resizeToAvoidBottomPadding`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomPadding.html) which is deprecated.

```
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false,
      body: YourWidgets(),
    );
```

Comment: They are the same answers @Ojonugwa, maybe the editor updated the accepted answer after I posted mine so now the difference is that mine includes an example?

Answer (score 41):

My approach is to use `SingleChildScrollView` with the `ClampingScrollPhysics` physics.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
  child: Container(),
)
```

Answer (score 22):

My suggestion is to use `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` anyway to prevent widgets from resizing if the keyboard suddenly appears on the screen. For example, if a user uses Facebook chat heads while in your app.

To prevent the keyboard from overlaying widgets, on screens where you need it, I suggest the following approach, where is the height of `SingleChildScrollView` reduced to the height of the available space. In this case, `SingleChildScrollView` also scrolls to the focused widget.

```
final double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
final double keyboardHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  body: SizedBox(
    height: screenHeight - keyboardHeight,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 200),
          for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) const TextField()
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 11):

The best solution to **avoid resizing widgets** and also **focus on the text field** is to use `SingleChildScrollView()` with `ClampingScrollPhysics()` physics. Also, remember to **set height** for its **child** (ex: use `container()`), so you can use your widgets through `Column()`:

```
return Scaffold(
   body: SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
      child: Container(
         height: size.height,
         child: Column(
            children:[
               TextFormField()
            ],
         ),
      ),
   ),
);
```

Answer (score 10):

Might Be too late to answer but the following worked for me

```dart
Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(parent: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()),
      child: Container(
```

Clamping will auto scroll to make textfield visible, its parent NeverScrollable will not allow the user to scroll.

Answer (score 7):

**Method 1:** Remove `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` from AndroidManifest.xml file (Otherwise it will override flutter code) and add `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false` in Scaffold like below:

```
Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar()
)
```

**Method 2(Not Recommended):** Just Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"` in android AndroidManifest.xml in activity it will only work for Android an Not for IOS like.

```
<activity
       ...
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible">
```

**Note:** Don't set it to `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

Answer (score 7):

[image]

**Feature**:

- Background image does not resize when keyboard is opened
- Ability to scroll elements hidden behind the keyboard

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

SizedBox addPaddingWhenKeyboardAppears() {
  final viewInsets = EdgeInsets.fromWindowPadding(
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.viewInsets,
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.devicePixelRatio,
  );

  final bottomOffset = viewInsets.bottom;
  const hiddenKeyboard = 0.0; // Always 0 if keyboard is not opened
  final isNeedPadding = bottomOffset != hiddenKeyboard;

  return SizedBox(height: isNeedPadding ? bottomOffset : hiddenKeyboard);
}

/// The size of the screen.
class ScreenSizeService {
  final BuildContext context;

  const ScreenSizeService(
    this.context,
  );

  Size get size => MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  double get height => size.height;
  double get width => size.width;
}

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final _imageUrl =
      'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1631823460501-e0c045fa716f?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyNHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60';

  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = ScreenSizeService(context).width;
    final screenHeight = ScreenSizeService(context).height;

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage(_imageUrl),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minWidth: screenWidth,
              minHeight: screenHeight,
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ...List.generate(6, (index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 60,
                        width: double.maxFinite,
                        color: Colors.pink[100],
                        child: Center(child: Text('$index')),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 40),
                    ],
                  );
                }),
                Container(color: Colors.white, child: const TextField()),
                addPaddingWhenKeyboardAppears(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Setting the value `false` for `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` worked fine for me.

Also, `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` worked fine for me. You can use either one.

Comment: You cannot use either one, the latter is deprecated with Flutter v1.1.9. 
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/1-22-deprecations#scaffoldresizetoavoidbottompadding

Comment: Would be more useful if you mentioned where that goes

Comment: @West You can set the value to inside Scaffold Widget

Comment: @DarkMikey You are right. Now, you need to set the value for resizeToAvoidBottomInset.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the use case you could also consider using a [listview](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html). That would ensure that the contents scroll when there is not enough room. As an example, you can look at the [textfield](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/text_form_field_demo.dart) demo in the gallery app

Comment: But this still doesn't make the TextField you selected to be visible, the keyboard will still overlap it. You have to scroll it yourself. Not used to as an Android developer / user

Answer (score 3):

Well I think if we implement @Aman's solution it will make our app behaves ugly as when the keyboard appears, it will not adjust our viewport of the screen as per available height and it will make out other fields hide behind the keyboard. So I would suggest use`SingleChildScrollView` instead.

Wrap your code with `SingleChildScrollView` as given below,

```
 return new Container(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: new Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      new Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: convertFrom,
      ),
      new Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: convertTo,
      ),
      new Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: description,
      ),
    ],
  ),
 ),
);
```

Comment: you are aware of the fact that this will immediately throw a mass of errors because the expanded widget will have infinite space to fill given by the singlechildscrollview

Answer (score 3):

For me changing below item property from true to false

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
```

in file

```
android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml
```

has made Flutter drag all page content upwards on input focus

[image: Flutter drag all page content upwards on input focus]

Comment: this will be only working for android as it appears...

Answer (score 3):

i had same problem with my screen and here how i fix it :

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, 
  ... 
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, 
  ... 
)
```

or you can wrap your widgets in

```
SingleChildScrollView
```

Answer (score 3):

My approach is to use `SingleChildScrollView` with the **BouncingScrollPhysics physics**.

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  child: Container(),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the **perfect** solution that gives you the ability to have a **full-screen column** inside of a **SingleChildScrollView**. This allows you to create a perfect layout for **all screen sizes** + the ability to have a scrollable screen that **only** scrolls if you open the keyboard or if the screen overflows after rendering (e.g. text input field validation)

```
class PerfectFullScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const PerfectFullScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                        (MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top + kToolbarHeight)),
                child: IntrinsicHeight(
                    child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: randomImageHeight,
                      child: Image.asset(
                        "assets/images/change_password.png",
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child: WidgetThatShouldTakeRemainingSpace() )
                  ],
                )))),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

The important part is the **ConstrainedBox** with the correct **BoxConstraints** and the **InstrinsicHeight** Widget.

PS: (MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top + kToolbarHeight) == Height of the Appbar

Comment: From the [docs of IntrinsicHeight](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html) (emphasis mine): "This class is relatively expensive, because it adds a speculative layout pass before the final layout phase. **Avoid using it where possible.** In the worst case, this widget can result in a layout that is O(N²) in the depth of the tree.". Advertising it as perfect using a widget that is recommended to be avoided if possible with plenty alternatives around might be a bit misleading.

Answer (score 2):

This will scroll with your keypad and collapse size when keyboard disappears.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return Padding(
            padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
            child:SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            child: Container(.......)));
```

Answer (score 2):

For a login screen or similar, in addition to solutions provided by all other top answers, I would also add `reverse: true` on `SingleChildScrollView`. These screens typically consist of some image or logo at the top half, and some text fields (username, password) and a button (sign in) at the bottom.

So in this particular case (which I constantly encounter, and I refer to this thread mostly because of it), it makes sense to scroll all the way down, so that all the text fields and button(s) are visible.

Code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        reverse: true,
        physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: PutYourContentHere(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the latest version of flutter `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` is deprecated and should not be used, now you must use `resizeToAvoidBottomInset`.

**Example:**

```
class YourWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const YourWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, // this property here
       body: ...
    )
  }
}
```

**Warning: you can only use this if your Widget has a Scaffold, otherwise you'll have to search specifically your case.**

Answer (score 0):

This strange behavoiur of media query when we click on textfield and keyBoard open media query rebulid one more same page in stack.

***MaterialApp(
useInheritedMediaQuery: true,)***

useInheritedMediaQuery to true will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Within the `Scaffold`, set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` property to `false`.

However, if you want to have certain `Widgets` resize within a `ListView` after setting the `Scaffold`, then here is a solution I am currently using:

```
class _YourCustomWidgetState extends State<YourCustomWidget> {

  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  final FocusNode _focusableWidgetNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final double keyboardHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;

    // This is just if you want to have the last focusable Widget scroll into view:
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      if (_focusableWidgetNode.hasPrimaryFocus) {
        // Tweak this if you want to change where you want to scroll to but 
        // it should be rarely necessary:
        final double bottomOffset = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
        _scrollController.animateTo(bottomOffset,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100), curve: Curves.linear);
      }
    });

  return Column(
   children: [
    // Widgets
    ListView(
      controller: _scrollController,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
         // Just ensure this is set:
         bottom: keyboardHeight
      ),
      children: [
        // Widgets
      ],
    ),
    // Widgets
  ],
);
  }

}
```

Alternatively, a `SingleChildScrollView` as suggested by others is another way but I've found it doesn't work well if you have `Widgets` between a `ListView` like I do.

Answer (score 0):

in scafolld
set this

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

The Scaffold property *resizeToAvoidBottomInset* does the job. And from the documentation, https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomInset.html, this property is a boolean, so setting it to false does the trick. Here is a use case:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
    appBar: AppBar(
      toolbarHeight: 50,
      leading: const Icon(
        Icons.menu,
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 138, 60, 55),
      ),
      title: const Text(
        'Tokyo',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'DM Serif Display',
          fontSize: 30.0,
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 138, 60, 55),
        ),
      ),
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
    ),
    body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          // Add your widgets here
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

A screenshot is also provided.

[resizeToAvoidBottomInset example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnvNG.png)

Answer (score -2):

I was facing the same issue and I started to try random solutions to fix it and suddenly this fixed it.

Wrap the main parent container within a SingleChildScrollView() and give it the device height i.e device_height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.

This will make the entire page scrollable but does not resize any widget.

Comment: Posting screenshots of code is discourated as it doesn't allow members to copy and play around with it themselves in easy fashion.

Comment: Hey, I was new to stackoverflow that time and I did not know how to add code to your answer. I would have edited the answer later, but I do not have the code anymore.

Comment: @RudrThakur copy it from your screenshot :P

Comment: deleted the image because some people don't understand that everyone is a beginner at some point