# Making a persistent background image while staying responsive in Flutter

Tags: dart, responsive, flutter

I'm creating a login screen, and i have this background image,
the problem is when the user clicks one of the `TextFields` and the keyboard pops, the background image changes its size to fit the new screen size (excluding the keyboard).

I want the background to stay persistent and the same size, i would use `BoxFit.none`, but i'm afraid it will hurt the responsiveness of the app.

Here's the code:

```
new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.red,
          image: new DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              image: new AssetImage(
                  'assets/images/splash_screen/background.png'))),
      child: new Center(
        child: new ListView(
          physics: new PageScrollPhysics(),
          children: <Widget>[ //Login screen content ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I also tried to define `BoxConstraints` with `minHeight` of the device screen but it doesn't help, and used `Stack` as well but with not luck.

Here's what i mean by changing dimensions:
[No Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf3us.jpg) / [With Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc9f0.jpg)

Comment: Maybe this will help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551268/when-the-keyboard-appears-the-flutter-widgets-resize-how-to-prevent-this

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Put your Scaffold as a child of a Container and make it transparent

```
final emailField = TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Email",
  ),
);

return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage('assets/bg.png'),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
  child: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    body: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        emailField,
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Additionally, if you want a background color and image, add a `color` under `BoxDecoration`. You can also change the alignment of the image with `alignment` under `DecorationImage`

Comment: Thanks for this insight.

Answer (score 6):

Try using a Stack, with your image in a Positioned, with a BoxFit of `fill`. Then, set `top: 0.0`. This way, its height shouldn't be influenced by the height of the bottom of the screen (i.e. it shouldn't change when the keyboard comes up), and its size should remain the same.
Example:

```
return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Positioned(
      top: 0.0,
      child: Image.asset(
        'assets/images/splash_screen/background.png',
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      ),
    ),
    Center(
      child: ListView(
        physics: PageScrollPhysics(),
        children: <Widget>[ 
           //Login screen content
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: I had to set top, left and right to 0.0 and set height to MediaQuery.of(context).size.height

Answer (score 3):

Try going to to your Scaffold (or use one) and set 
`resizeToAvoidBottomPadding = false`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, It  works well

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class SignUpView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/background.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ))),
      Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('NEW USER'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
          ),
          body: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: ListView(children: <Widget>[])))
    ]);
  }
}
```