# Making a scrollable page in Flutter

Tags: flutter

so I'm trying to make a registration page with multi fields for name and password and email etc.
my problem is that i couldn't make the page scrollable, can please help me with fixing that
I just want the page to be scrollable
Here is my Code :

```
class InstRegisterPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Color(0x47705C53), Color(0x9E36251D)],
              stops: [0.1, 0.9],
              begin: Alignment.topRight,
              end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: wLogo(),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 75,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xFFF7F6F5),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(26),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(26)),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 15,
                      ),
                      CSfield('Particpent Name',''),
                      CSfieldEmail('Email',''),
                      CSfield('Password',''),
                      CSPasswordFiled('Phone Number',''),
                      CSButton(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          //child: InstHomePageWidgets(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wrap your column with a SingleChildScroll view. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `Column` with a [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) to make it scrollable.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: [...]
  ),
)
```

Comment: I also do that, it worked fine. Are there any other alternatives? Because handling keyboard seems to difficult in this way.

Comment: What is the issue with the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the page [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets/scrolling) to see all the scrollable widgets.

Also if the keyboard is pushes content up you can check [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840074/keyboard-pushes-the-content-up-resizes-the-screen)