# inactive InputConnection

Tags: flutter, dart

I implement `textformfield` in form . I run in android emulator when I click text field,keyboard show and close instantly and get error . In iOS emulator run perfectly only error in Android.[error screen record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoaHZ.gif)

When I try delete form and convert `textformfield` to `formfield` it works perfectly. I think there are android error about form. What can I do?

**Error:**

> W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10839): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10839): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10839): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10839): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10839): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection

**Form:**

```
SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Form(
                    key: formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: entryField(
                              title: "Haber Başlığı(Zorunlu)",
                              textEditingController: headerController,
                              faIcon: FaIcon(
                                FontAwesomeIcons.horseHead,
                                color: Colors.deepOrange,
                                size: 30,
                              )),
                        ),
                        lineDivider(),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 8, 8),
                          child: entryField(
                              title: "Haber İçeriği(Zorunlu)",
                              textEditingController: descController,
                              faIcon: FaIcon(
                                FontAwesomeIcons.userNinja,
                                color: Colors.deepOrange,
                                size: 30,
                              )),
                        ),
                        lineDivider(),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 8, 8),
                          child: entryField(
                              title: "Youtube Linki",
                              textEditingController: youtubeController,
                              faIcon: FaIcon(
                                FontAwesomeIcons.youtube,
                                color: Colors.deepOrange,
                                size: 30,
                              )),
                        ),
                        lineDivider(),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 8, 8),
                          child: entryField(
                              title: "Diğer Linkler",
                              textEditingController: otherController,
                              faIcon: FaIcon(
                                FontAwesomeIcons.slack,
                                color: Colors.deepOrange,
                                size: 30,
                              )),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

**Textformfield:**

```
Widget entryField(
{String title,
  TextEditingController textEditingController,
  FaIcon faIcon}) {
   return Container(
margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
child: Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(
      title,
      style: GoogleFonts.righteous(
          color: Colors.deepOrange,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 20),
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 10,
    ),
    TextFormField(
        validator: (e) {
          String yazilacak;

          if (title == "Haber Başlığı(Zorunlu)") {
            if (e.isEmpty) yazilacak = "Lütfen Başlığı giriniz";
          }
          if (title == "Haber İçeriği(Zorunlu)") {
            if (e.isEmpty) yazilacak = "Lütfen içeriği giriniz";
          }
          if (title == "Youtube Linki") {
            if (e != "" && !e.contains("youtube")) {
              if (!e.contains("youtu.be"))
                if(!e.contains("https"))
                  yazilacak = "Lütfen sadece youtube linki giriniz";
            } else {
              if(!e.contains("https://")&& e!="") yazilacak="Lütfen https:// ekleyin";
            }
          }
          return yazilacak;
        },
        maxLines: null,
        style: GoogleFonts.roboto(color: Colors.limeAccent),
        controller: textEditingController,
        cursorColor: Colors.limeAccent,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        maxLength: title == "Haber Başlığı(Zorunlu)" ? 35 : 200,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            counterStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.limeAccent),
            hoverColor: Colors.limeAccent,
            focusColor: Colors.limeAccent,
            suffixIcon: faIcon,
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.limeAccent),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.lime),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.lime)),
            fillColor: Colors.white12,
            errorStyle: GoogleFonts.adventPro(
                fontSize: 15,
                color: Colors.limeAccent,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            filled: true))
        ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Where is your `formKey` defined ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: keyboard disappears immediately when editing my text fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51320692/flutter-keyboard-disappears-immediately-when-editing-my-text-fields)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is about formkey defination location. I was defined in build section . Now I define in init state and its okay.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MVVM, define your formkey in ViewModel.

Comment: provide some more information, explain it in detail.