# Flutter: pushNamed makes TextFormField to malfunction?

Tags: flutter, keyboard, textformfield

My problem is similar to the [Flutter: keyboard disappears immediately when editing my text fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51320692/flutter-keyboard-disappears-immediately-when-editing-my-text-fields). I have tried all answers from the mentioned above article but nothing made a difference. I realized that the pushReplacementNamed "fixed" the problem.

If I open the screen with Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(routeName) everything works properly. If I open the screen with Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(routeName) and touch the TextFormField, the keyboard appears and then instantly disappears.

As for the test code I have put a lonely TextField on the page to observe the same behavior. I couldn't make it work with pushNamed. I am using Flutter version 3.10.2, Dart version 3.0.2.

Does anyone knows why or how to make it work?

Comment: Hmm, having the same side effects in go.router pushNamed. When routing done textfield focused and reloads the whole page! 

not sure what to do!