# What to do when the keyboard is hiding the form?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this design that I'm creating on **Flutter**:

[image]

Here is what I managed to do so far:

[image]

I'll provided you my code and I ll explain it and finally I'll try to explain the error that I'm having. First here is my code:

```dart
class CheckoutPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CheckoutPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<CheckoutPage> createState() => _CheckoutPageState();
}

class _CheckoutPageState extends State<CheckoutPage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Map<String, bool> isActive = {
    'Quantity': true,
    'Payment': false,
    'Review': false,
  };
  Map<String, bool> isDone = {
    'Quantity': false,
    'Payment': false,
    'Review': false,
  };
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    order = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Order;
    final PageController pageViewController = PageController();
    final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    final TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
    final TextEditingController phoneNumberController = TextEditingController();
    final TextEditingController addressController = TextEditingController();

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: height * 0.16,
                child: PageViewIndicator(isActive: isActive, isDone: isDone),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: height * 0.84,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 8,
                    vertical: 18,
                  ),
                  child: PageView(
                    controller: pageViewController,
                    children: [
                      QuantityStepWidget(
                        formKey: formKey,
                        addressController: addressController,
                        nameController: nameController,
                        phoneNumberController: phoneNumberController,
                      ),
                      const PaymentStepWidget(),
                      const ReviewStepWidget(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const BackButtonWidget(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This code is mainly composed of a `Scaffold`, it's child is a `Stack` that stacks a back button (`BackButton`) on tap of a `Column`. This column has two containers `SizedBox`; the first one takes 16% of the height of the screen, and the second one takes 84% which makes a total of 100%. Inside the first `SizedBox` I defined a `PageViewIndicator` widget which is a `Container` that holds a `Row` that holds 3 `HeadingPageViewItemWidget` like this:

```dart
class PageViewIndicator extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, bool> isActive;
  final Map<String, bool> isDone;
  const PageViewIndicator({
    super.key,
    required this.isActive,
    required this.isDone,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(color: AppColors.borderColor),
        ),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0, bottom: 20),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            HeadingPageViewItemWidget(
              number: '1',
              title: 'Quantity',
              isActive: isActive['Quantity']!,
              isDone: isDone['Quantity']!,
            ),
            HeadingPageViewItemWidget(
              number: '2',
              title: 'Payment',
              isActive: isActive['Payment']!,
              isDone: isDone['Payment']!,
            ),
            HeadingPageViewItemWidget(
              number: '3',
              title: 'Review',
              isActive: isActive['Review']!,
              isDone: isDone['Review']!,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The `HeadingPageViewItemWidget` is another `Row` that holds a `CircleAvatar` and a `Text` widget, like this:

```dart
class HeadingPageViewItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String number;
  final String title;
  final bool isDone;
  final bool isActive;
  const HeadingPageViewItemWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.number,
    required this.title,
    this.isDone = false,
    this.isActive = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 100,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: _getColor(isDone: isDone, isActive: isActive),
            radius: 15,
            child: _getIconOrNumber(isDone),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 60,
            child: Text(title, style: kCaption0),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Inside the second `SizedBox` I have defined a `PageView` that has 3 children, `QuantityStepWidget`, `PaymentStepWidget` and `ReviewStepWidget`, these last two are just `PlaceHolder`s for the moment. The `QuantityStepWidget` is defined like this:

```dart
class QuantityStepWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey;
  final TextEditingController nameController;
  final TextEditingController phoneNumberController;
  final TextEditingController addressController;
  const QuantityStepWidget(
      {super.key,
      required this.formKey,
      required this.nameController,
      required this.phoneNumberController,
      required this.addressController});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Flexible(
              fit: FlexFit.loose,
              child: SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                  child: const TitleWidget(title: 'Quantity')),
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 3,
              fit: FlexFit.loose,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: MedicationCheckoutQuantityWidget(order: order),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 3,
              fit: FlexFit.loose,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      'Confirm your information',
                      style: kH3TitleStyle,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Flexible(
                      fit: FlexFit.loose,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 200,
                        child: Form(
                          key: formKey,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Flexible(
                                flex: 1,
                                fit: FlexFit.loose,
                                child:
                                    TextFormFieldUserInformationsConfirmationWidget(
                                  type: FormType.name,
                                  controller: nameController,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Flexible(
                                flex: 1,
                                fit: FlexFit.loose,
                                child:
                                    TextFormFieldUserInformationsConfirmationWidget(
                                  type: FormType.phoneNumber,
                                  controller: phoneNumberController,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Flexible(
                                flex: 1,
                                fit: FlexFit.loose,
                                child:
                                    TextFormFieldUserInformationsConfirmationWidget(
                                  type: FormType.address,
                                  controller: addressController,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    ButtonWidget(
                        onPressed: () {
                          print('lol');
                          if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                            print(nameController.text);
                            print(phoneNumberController.text);
                            print(addressController.text);
                          }
                        },
                        text: 'Confirm'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It consists of a `SingleChildScrollView` and inside it there is a `Column` which holds thre `Flexible` widgets; the first one is the 'Quantity' title, the second one is the two cards of the medication name and quantity, and the third one is the form.

What I want is to make the form go up when the keyboard gets triggered, but it doesn't want to do that, all it does is to show the keyboard and then close it instanly, and it doesn't give me the time to add text, as soon as the keyboard opens it closes

Comment: the problem is with your builder, it is called by default whenever keyboad opens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put These Two outside of your build method:

```
final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

For more information, visit this thread: [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51320692/flutter-keyboard-disappears-immediately-when-editing-my-text-fields)

Comment: moving the GlobalKey fixed my problem, but you can't move the height because it requires the context. Thanks for fixing my problem!

Comment: do you know how to make the form go up when they keyboard shows up ? Because now the keyaboard stays on top of it

Comment: @Mikelenjilo wrap it in single child scroll view