# InputConnectionAdaptor(7041): The input method toggled cursor monitoring on/off problem in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm encountering an issue during the signup process. I'm unable to sign up, and the error message for signup failure and authentication validation isn't displaying. The debug console is showing the following error:

**InputConnectionAdaptor(7041): The input method toggled cursor monitoring on
InputConnectionAdaptor(7041): The input method toggled cursor monitoring off
**
Could you please assist me with resolving this issue as soon as possible the code is given below?

```
enum Auth { sigin, signup }

class AuthScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = '/auth-screen';
  const AuthScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<AuthScreen> createState() => _AuthScreenState();
}

class _AuthScreenState extends State<AuthScreen> {
  Auth _auth = Auth.signup;
  final _signUpFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _signInFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final AuthSevice authSevice = AuthSevice();
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    _nameController.dispose();
  }

  void signUpUser() {
    authSevice.signUpUser(
      context: context,
      email: _emailController.text,
      password: _passwordController.text,
      name: _nameController.text,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: GlobalVariables.greyBackgroundCOlor,
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Text(
              'Welcome',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 22,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              tileColor: _auth == Auth.signup
                  ? GlobalVariables.backgroundColor
                  : GlobalVariables.greyBackgroundCOlor,
              title: const Text(
                'Create Account',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              leading: Radio(
                activeColor: GlobalVariables.secondaryColor,
                value: Auth.signup,
                groupValue: _auth,
                onChanged: (Auth? val) {
                  setState(() {
                    _auth = val!;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            if (_auth == Auth.signup)
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                color: GlobalVariables.backgroundColor,
                child: Form(
                  key: _signUpFormKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      CustomTextField(
                        controller: _nameController,
                        hintText: 'Name',
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      CustomTextField(
                        controller: _emailController,
                        hintText: 'Email',
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      CustomTextField(
                        controller: _passwordController,
                        hintText: 'Password',
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      CustomButton(
                          text: 'Sign Up',
                          onTap: () {
                            if (_signInFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                              signUpUser();
                            }
                          }),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ListTile(
              tileColor: _auth == Auth.sigin
                  ? GlobalVariables.backgroundColor
                  : GlobalVariables.greyBackgroundCOlor,
              title: const Text(
                'Sign-In',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              leading: Radio(
                activeColor: GlobalVariables.secondaryColor,
                value: Auth.sigin,
                groupValue: _auth,
                onChanged: (Auth? val) {
                  setState(() {
                    _auth = val!;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            if (_auth == Auth.sigin)
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                color: GlobalVariables.backgroundColor,
                child: Form(
                  key: _signInFormKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      CustomTextField(
                        controller: _emailController,
                        hintText: 'Email',
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      CustomTextField(
                        controller: _passwordController,
                        hintText: 'Password',
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      CustomButton(text: 'Sign In', onTap: () {}),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

I searched and discovered a suggestion to use stateful widgets instead of stateless ones. However, even though I've already implemented this change, the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the initialization of `FormState`.

You should change this part:

```
final _signUpFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
final _signInFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

into this:

```
late final _signUpFormKey;
late final _signInFormKey;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _signUpFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    _signInFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  }
```

[Flutter: keyboard disappears immediately when editing my text fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51320692/flutter-keyboard-disappears-immediately-when-editing-my-text-fields)