# How to push up TextFormField to enable user input flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have this TextFormFields in a scrollView. The top 2 TextFormFields allow the user to see what they are typing. However, on clicking the third TextFormField, the keyboard appears above the TextFormField and hides it so the user does not see what they are typing. How can I correct this.
On clicking the first one.

[image: Img 1].

Clicking the Third One, it is hidden partially

[image: img 2]

Clicking the fourth, nothing can be seen at all. Keyboard obscures it [image: Nothing can be seen at all. Keyboard obscures it]

The Code I have

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 200.0,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Form(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
                      labelText: 'One',
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      isDense: true,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
                      labelText: 'Two',
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      isDense: true,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
                  labelText: 'Three',
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  isDense: true,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

The normal default android keyboard used[image]

Comment: It seems like this is caused by your really strange system keyboard (one that can be moved around). I would say that 99.9% of all users have a normal keyboard that is attached to the bottom of the screen, and in that case everything works correctly

Comment: I think the keyboard is Gboard, and there are a lot of people that use Gboard. This post https://stackoverflow.com/q/46551268/8954451 has the problem the other way around, so maybe you can get some idea from it.

Comment: You could also try to run it and give me feedback. I have attached the screenshot using the default android keyboard and the problem for me persists

Comment: I ran it and I have the same problem, I think your structure isn't right. Why do you want to have it 200.0 from the top?

Comment: That is a different Container. From the screenshot it is black in color. It could hold text or something else in future. I dont want it to be part of the scrollView.

Comment: Actually, I have no problem with it being part of the scrollView. As long as the keyboard issue is gone