# How can I avoid the background image to shrink when my keyboard is active?

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to have a background image with text inputs but I don't know which widget I should use to avoid the background image to shrink when my keyboard is active.

Here you can find two screen shots of the problem and my code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var backgroundImage = new BoxDecoration(
        image: new DecorationImage(
            image: new AssetImage('assets/forest.jpg'), fit: BoxFit.cover));

    return new MaterialApp(
        home: new Scaffold(
            body: new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          decoration: backgroundImage,
        ),
        new TextField()
      ],
    )));
  }
}
```

[closed keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcZ0L.jpg)
[active keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bxRj.jpg)

Comment: Use resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, resizeToAvoidBottomPadding is deprecated.  [Flutter login page with background Example](https://androidride.com/flutter-background-image/#bg_login_page)  -

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the property `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` from `Scaffold` :

```
Scaffold(
     resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
     ...
```

Comment: This works great but what if I have content that  I would also like to scroll? Lets say I have form with TextFormField and I want to see it above keyboard - so it needs to scroll up with keyboard.

Any idea?

Comment: @ŽanFras, please look https://stackoverflow.com/a/70428060/2646022 for scrollable screen with static background image

Answer (score 14):

Put Container outside of Scaffold, and make Scaffold as a child of Container with the background image.

```
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage('assets/bg.png'),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
  child: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    body: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Email",
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 7):

It's the default functionality of the flutter to keep UI above the keyboard so if you set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false` then you will lose the functionality of keeping your UI components above the keyboard

To have a background image in your application, and not to shrink it
better way is to do it like this

```
Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: primaryColor,                                       
    image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage(AppImages.appBg)),// background image above color
),
child: SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,                          //**IMPORTANT**
        body: //All Ui code here//),
),
```

It is **necessary** to set **Scaffold backgroundColor: Colors.transparent**
otherwise, you won't be able to see your background image