# All widgets resize when keyboard is shown in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a layout with two `TextField` and I am worried about all the items being resized when the keyboard is shown.

The layouts with and without the keyboard are in the picture below.

[image: layout without keyboard][image: layout with keyboard]

When the keyboard is shown all the widgets (`TextField` `Text` and `Button`) resize to the top.

As my widgets are wrapped into a `SingleChildScrollView`, even if the screen is small we can scroll to see all the items, therefore, there isn't a problem.

```
Widget _buildCamposLogin() {
  return Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0, left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildLoginText(),
            _buildCampoCPF(),
            _buildCampoSenha(),
            _buildSubmitButton(),
            _buildCadastroText(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

So, the problem is I feel weird about moving everything to the top, shouldn't be better to move only the `TextField` which was focused and the other things above this `TextField`, instead of moving everything above and below the `TextField` which was focused.

If you think this is better, what would be the solution to move only the `TextField` and widgets above to the top?

**Why my question is not duplicated**

In the marked question, the guy asks how to prevent the keyboard from moving the widgets. And the answers say to set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` in the `Scaffold`. That's is completely different from what I am asking.

I do want the keyboard to move the widgets to the top as it does. The problem is that it moves all my widgets, the 2 `TextField` the `RaisedButton` and the 2 `Text` at the bottom. I would like to move only the `TextField` which was shown as the following example.

Note the difference between these two pictures below and the others I've already uploaded.

[image: Layout I desire without keyboard][image: Layout I desire with keyboard]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When the keyboard appears, the Flutter widgets resize. How to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551268/when-the-keyboard-appears-the-flutter-widgets-resize-how-to-prevent-this)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand to summarize the question, you're looking to retain the size the background elements on the Screen. Preventing the background to be resized when the softkeyboard appears.

As mentioned in the comments, the [workarounds posted in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551268/when-the-keyboard-appears-the-flutter-widgets-resize-how-to-prevent-this) seems applicable to your use case. The [Scaffold.resizeToAvoidBottomInset](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomInset.html) can be set to `false` to prevent resizing when the keyboard appears.