# Flutter: Keyboard causing a renderflex overflow error

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to display a message to the user unless there is a renderflex overflow error of 212px at the bottom. Actually, I use a separate widget to display the message, and every time I try to type with my phone, I get an error. I tried several solutions but none of them worked for me.
I would appreciate it if someone took a look. Thanks in advance!

**Here is my code:**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
          'Passation chat',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Text('Messages'),
          Container(
            height: 590,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                physics: ScrollPhysics(), reverse: true, child: ShowMessages()),
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border(
                          top: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 0.2))),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: msgController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Message'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (msgController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                      storeMessage.collection('Messages').doc().set({
                        "msg": msgController.text.trim(),
                        "user": logInUser!.email.toString(),
                        "time": DateTime.now()
                      });
                      msgController.clear();
                      FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
                    }
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.send,
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  ))
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ShowMessages extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Messages')
          .orderBy('time')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            QueryDocumentSnapshot x = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
            return ListTile(
              title: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: logInUser!.email == x['user']
                    ? CrossAxisAlignment.end
                    : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Column(children: [
                      Text(x['msg']),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        x['user'],
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                      )
                    ]),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: logInUser!.email == x['user']
                            ? Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.2)
                            : Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.1),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
          shrinkWrap: true,
          primary: true,
          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Screenshots from the app:**

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When the keyboard appears, the Flutter widgets resize. How to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551268/when-the-keyboard-appears-the-flutter-widgets-resize-how-to-prevent-this)

Comment: and [Bottom overflowed by x pixels when showing keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67571423/10157127)

Answer (score 1):

Make `SingleChildScrollView` the first widget of `Scaffold` body.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by wrapping the Column widget by a `SingleChildScrollView`. Thanks mates!