# How to open keyboard over the screen without pushing the contents up automatically?

Tags: flutter, keyboard, overriding, focus, screen

At the moment my app works like following:

When the dialog is opened:
[image]

When user clicks on `textFormFields` to inter some text:
[image]

What I am looking for to do is to keep Dialog's( or all the contents on the screen) same as before and keyboard just comes over them without changing their size or view.

How can I do that?

***`EDIT`: I need something like `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` that works only with `Scaffold` but for other kind of widgets like `Dialog`.***

Comment: or are you trying to make it minimal view on dialog, like on second image? the question is lacking of debuging details, a sample minimal widget will explain better. More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh: No the current behavior is like the photos I have put in the question. What I want to do is disabling this behavior and keyboard just overlaps the normal screen.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh: The answer by @Nikita Shadkov suggests what I want, but it only works with `Scaffold` and I need something that works with other widgets like `Dialog` as well.

Comment: It is still not clear to me how the UI will represent when the keyboard will pop. More about [asking good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh: I think this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69234481/20706987) answers my question but I was looking for a simpler property of Flutter itself.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh: Could you have a look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75730093/how-to-create-a-list-of-videoplayer-widgets-in-flutter

Answer (score 1):

You can use `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to implement this behaviour.

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  ...
)
```

original answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46551390/10766511)

Comment: What about the widgets? For example my question is about a Dialog widget that doesn't have such a property.

Comment: you're always can wrap it with any widget you want) at least could try.
I will suggest parse this property in the nearest Scaffold you have, and if it won't work, just wrap your dialog